# Как посчитать количество чисел в файле (состоящем только из натуральных чисел) в С++

Tags: c++, файлы

Как мне считать из файла числа в какой-нибудь массив char или string так, чтобы я мог посчитать кол-во этих чисел (например "2", "324" "11" и любого другого числа). Функция sizeof или метод size() не работают. Не могли бы вы предложить какую-нибудь конструкцию, идею как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Вас интересуют *цифры* или *числа*?

Comment: Какая-то путаница... Вы понимаете разницу между цифрой и числом?

Comment: Числа, извиняюсь

Comment: Если нужно считать все числа из файла, то можно просто загонять их, например, в вектор. Если нельзя использовать конейнеры, то можно реализовать самому логику увеличения размера массива. Если же просто нужно узнать количество чисел в файле, то можно просто читать по одному числу и считать их количество.

Comment: Число чисел в файле состоящем только из чисел и простых разделителей скорее всего равно числу разделителей + 1.

Comment: Для решения вашей задачи совсем не нужно хранить где-либо сами числа. Читайте по символу. Если прочитанный символ это цифра, то увеличте количество чисел, но далее, пока не встретится не цифра, более его не увеличивайте. Повторяйте до конца файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто читать и считать числа...

```
int x, counter = 0;
{
    ifstream in(filename);
    while(in >> x) counter++;
}

cout << counter;
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно! Всем спасибо!